# How can I send a request to a view from an admin command without hard coding the url

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to create an admin command that will simulate some api calls associated with a view but I don't want to hard code the url, for example like that `url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/viewname'`, in order to send the request.

If I use the reverse option I can obtain half the url `/api/viewname`. 
If I try to post the request that way

```
url = reverse('name-of-view')
requests.post(url, data=some_data)
```

I get

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/viewname/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/viewname/?
```

Do I have to look whether the server is running on the localhost or is there a more generic way?

Comment: Why do you need the full URL? Why wouldn't the relative link work?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

`requests` module needs the absolute url to post to. you need

```
url = 'http://%s%s' % (request.META['HTTP_HOST'], reverse('name-of-view'))     
requests.post(url, data=some_data)
```

Comment: But there is no request.

Comment: then get the site name via Sites model ;) @PGryllos